# Delphi - Creating a package that uses GDI+ and compatible with c++ Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, header, gdi+, generated

I'm writing a Delphi package with RAD Studio XE7, in which several classes may paint graphical elements with GDI+. This code works well as long as I use it with Delphi projects.

However I also need to create C++ projects, which use the same package. I noticed that all of the .hpp headers for which the matching unit contains some GDI+ code must be manually modified to be used in C++ after generated by the compiler, which is very annoying. It's as if GDI+ for Delphi and for C++ use 2 completely different code, which one have nothing to do with the other, and for which the declarations in one language have no correspondance in the other and vice versa. So a simple Delphi function like

```pascal
function GetGDIPlusPen: TGpPen; inline;
```

is exported incorrectly in the auto-generated .hpp, because TGpPen in Delphi is called Gdiplus::Pen in C++, and for that the function provided in my .hpp is completely incompatible and must be corrected manually - or commented to be deactivated in the worstest case.

I know that several compiler directives exist to influence the generation of the.hpp file content, however I never found a such directive to prohibit a given function to be generated in the .hpp file, and to replace his declaration by another that the c++ compiler may understand. If anybody know such directives, please let me know.

I also took a look on how other people resolved this issue in several libraries over the internet, it seems that many developers prefer to write their own GDI+ wrapper instead of using the Winapi.Gdipapi and Winapi.Gdipobj default units provided by the RAD studio.

So, is there a simple way to notify the compiler to generate the correct C++ code in the auto-generated .hpp files in which GDI+ is used? Or the only solution is to write my own wrapper around GDI+? How can I use GDI+ to not disturb the generation of my .hpp files?

Regards

**------------------ UPDATE --------------------**

I realize that my question may be a little bit obscure. In fact I have several classes that contain some GDI+ code, in several units. When the .hpp is generated, some functions like e.g.

```pascal
TWColor = record
    ...
    function GetGDIPlusPen: TGpPen; inline;
    ...
```

are generated this way in the .hpp file:

```cpp
struct DECLSPEC_DRECORD TWColor
{
    ...
    Winapi::Gdipobj::TGPSolidBrush* __fastcall GetGDIPlusSolidBrush(void);
    ...
```

Of course this will not work. So what I try to do is:

1. Notify the compiler that the GetGDIPlusSolidBrush() function should not be generated inside the .hpp file
2. Replace this function by another custom definition, like e.g.

```cpp
struct DECLSPEC_DRECORD TWColor
{
    ...
    Gdiplus::SolidBrush* __fastcall GetGDIPlusSolidBrush(void);
    ...
```

The question is: is there a way to do that?

Regards

Comment: "*I never found a such directive to prohibit a given function to be generated in the .hpp file ...*" - see `{$EXTERNALSYM}` or `{$NODEFINE}`. "*and to replace his declaration by another that the c++ compiler may understand.*" - see `{$HPPEMIT}`.

Comment: Delphi can't access C++ classes and C++ namespaces, so Delphi projects use GDI+'s C-style flat API inside of Delphi wrapper classes.  C++ projects have access to GDI+'s full C++ based API instead.  So yes, they are using very different code. The Delphi classes should be usable in C++, you just can't mix them with actual GDI+ C++ classes.

Comment: Thx for the replies, @Remy: I already tried to surround several specific functions with {$EXTERNALSYM} or {$NODEFINE}, but seems not work in this case. AFAIK {$EXTERNALSYM} can stop the generation of a symbol like PWColor = ^TWColor; and {$NODEFINE} prohibits the include of a particular unit. Also {$HPPEMIT} emits code on the top (or bottom) of my .hpp file, but not e.g. immediately after a function I want to alter. So can you please be more specific, e.g. by providing a short example? Once again thank you.

Comment: `{$EXTERNALSYM}` and `{$NODEFINE}` work equally fine with types, variables, and stand-alone functions. And yes, you don't have much control over `{$HPPEMIT}`, but as long as you are just declaring functions than you should be able to use it.  You can't use these directives to alter the declarations of class members, though.  Is that what you are trying to do? Like I said, you can't mix the Delphi-based and C++-based APIs anyway, so why are you even trying?  Just use the Delphi-based API by itself and it should work.

Comment: thx Remy, I posted more info above, I hope this will clarify the situation

Comment: You haven't explained why you need to change the Delphi declarations at all instead of using them as-is. What is the actual conflict you are trying to avoid? Can you show an example?

Comment: In fact the issue appear with my class or record function names, when using GDI+, where the compiler generate names like Winapi::Gdipobj::TGPSolidBrush instead of Gdiplus::SolidBrush while the .hpp files are generated, as shown in the above example. Such names not exist in C++. For now my only solution is to edit each .hpp manually and change the declaration myself. I wanted to know if a better solution exist, e.g. with compiler directives, or if the only way to avoid that is to write a wrapper around GDI+